# How to solve XOR equations like A xor ( A - 4 ) = 5?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor, bitwise-xor

Actually I an trying to solve "Xoring Ninja" in Hackerrank.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/xoring-ninja/problem

> Let A be a set of N elements {a1, a2, ......, aN}
>
> The XORSUM of set A is defined here as the sum of the XOR's of all A's
>   non-empty subsets.

Let S = XORSUM

S = (a1 + a2 + ... + aN) + [(a1 ^ a2) + (a1 ^ aN) + ..] + {3 sized subsets} + ... + (a1 ^ a2 ^ ..... ^ aN)

Let T = (a1 ^ a2 ^ .... ^ aN)

then S = T ^ (S - T)

S ^ S = S ^ T ^ (S - T)

0 = T ^ S ^ (S - T)

T ^ 0 = T ^ T ^ S ^ (S - T)

T = S ^ (S - T)

I wanted to know how to solve any equations that involve + - * / with bitwise operators?

Answer (score 0):

A XOR (A - 4) = 5

The binary representation of 5 is 101, so we know that A and A - 4 have the very same bit values, except the first one and the third one (from right to left). Since the fourth digit is unchanged (otherwise the number would be greater or equal than 8), so the third bit of A was 1, but the most important clue is that 5 is odd and we are XOR-ing A with A - 4. We know that the value of the last bit of a number determines whether it is pair or odd and we know that subtracting or adding a pair number to an integer will leave it odd if it was odd and will leave it pair if it was pair, So A - 4 will be odd if A was odd and will be pair if A was pair. Bitwise XOR-ing a pair number with another pair number or an odd number with another odd number will result in a pair number. So, A XOR (A - 4) = 5 has no solution for unsigned integers if we have infinite memory space allocated to them.

This is how you can solve it in your mind. Of course, a more detailed explanation could be given for each type of equation, but the solution of any equation type involving bitwise operations is a complete field which spans beyond the borders of a SO answer. If you want to program this, then you will have a difficult project to implement, but always start from the simplest, the evident.